# Returning from setInterval in JavaScript/React.js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return a value from my setInterval function. My code looks like that:

```
export const timeCounter = () => {
  const date = "2018-08-12T18:45:00.000Z"; //this is just mocked data
  const matchDate = new Date(date);

  let dateToShow;

  const showTime = () => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const distance = matchDate - currentDate;

    return dateToShow = distance < 0 ? "FINISHED" : null;
  };


  const timer = setInterval(showTime, 1000);
  console.log(timer) // here I'd like to see refreshing value (FINISHER or nothing)
};
```

What I'm trying to do is to run my interval every second with showTime function. What I need to return is just "FINISHED" or nothing. But console.log(timer) won't give refreshed status.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: how it's react related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that timer is set to the result of the `setInterval` function, not the return value of the function within `setInterval`. `setInterval` just returns a reference that you can use to cancel it.

If you pass a callback function into the timer, it'll be able to run that function once it reaches the condition you set:

```js
const timeCounter = () => {
  const date = "2018-08-12T18:45:00.000Z"; //this is just mocked data
  const matchDate = new Date(date);

  let dateToShow;

  const showTime = (callback) => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const distance = matchDate - currentDate;

    return dateToShow = distance < 0 ? callback("FINISHED") : null;
  };


  const logWhenDone = logData => console.log(logData)

  const timer = setInterval(() => {showTime(logWhenDone)}, 1000);
  
  // this is just the return value of the setInterval function, which is just a reference to that interval
  console.log(timer) 
};

timeCounter()
```

To return something from the function you need to handle the fact that the function is asynchronous, that is, it will evaluate to the return statement before it has the actual value it needs to return.

There are a few different ways to handle asynchronous code. One way would be to pass the callback into `timeCounter` as has been done with `showTime`. Another way is to return a `Promise`, that will resolve once the timer hits its end condition.

```js
const timeCounter = () => {
  const timerPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const date = "2018-08-12T18:45:00.000Z"; //this is just mocked data
    const matchDate = new Date(date);

    const showTime = () => {
      const currentDate = new Date();
      const distance = matchDate - currentDate;

      if (distance < 0) {
        return resolve("FINISHED");
      }
    };

    setInterval(showTime, 1000);
  });
  
  return timerPromise;
};

timeCounter().then(response => console.log(`The response is ${response}`));
```

---

**EDIT**
Based on what you've said regarding wanting to respond to every tick of the `setInterval`, you may want to consider using events instead:

```js
const date = "2018-08-12T18:45:00.000Z";
const matchDate = new Date(date);

setInterval(() => {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  const distance = matchDate - currentDate;
  
  var tick = new CustomEvent('tick', {
    detail: distance < 0 ? 'FINISHED' : '',
  });
  
  document.dispatchEvent(tick);
}, 1000);

document.addEventListener('tick', event => console.dir(event.detail));
```

Comment: Thank you! Just another question, how can I return that value instead of logging it?

Comment: @Barth do you mean you want to return it from the function `timeCounter`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, you're right.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a way to handle a return

Comment: Thank you! But will this code will run FINISHED only once?

Comment: @Barth Yes it will, did you want it to return `"FINISHED"` every time it goes through the interval? Functions only return once so the structure would need to be slightly different

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, but never user promises like this before...

Comment: @Barth I've added a version which use events, which are probably more appropriate for this than functions

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` does not return the string 'FINISHED' or null you expect but It returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the interval, so you can remove it later by calling `clearInterval()`. This method is offered on the Window and Worker interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

> Return Value: A Number, representing the ID value of the timer that is set. Use this value with the clearInterval() method to cancel the timer

you can log refreshing value inside showTime function:

```
const showTime = () => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const distance = matchDate - currentDate;

    dateToShow = distance < 0 ? 'FINISHED' : null;

    console.log(dateToShow);
};
```

or use component`s state if you want to refresh DOM